# Can't Center ImageView With Proper Constraints

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a simple ImageView that I want to center on the bottom edge of an ImageView in a ConstraintLayout. I know that it should work (based on other questions posted on StackOverflow) and I'm doing the same thing on a different view where I center an ImageView on the start edge of a View. Anybody seen cases when this doesn't work? I've rebuilt and restarted and cleared the cache of my Android Studio with no help.

Very simple layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder_header"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"


        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/artist_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/level_artist_image_placeholder"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/header_image"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/header_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/header_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header_image"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.32"

        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Resulting in:
[image]

Instead of:

[image]

Comment: Interesting problem. This looks like a bug to me. If you remove the width percentage and define a set width, it works like you would expect. Your layout does work in 2.0.0-beta4 if you can switch.

Comment: Yea I switched to 2.0.0 beta and started working

Answer (score 0):

changed the artist_image width and height to wrap_content and it worked for me, you can also set height and width in dp and it'll still work

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"


        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/artist_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/header_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/header_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/header_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header_image"
         />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Doing that takes away my ability to change the width and height using  `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.32"`

Comment: ok, then let me try with another method, will asnwer it again, if i get the solution

Answer (score 0):

I've copy pasted your `xml` (except `drawable`) into `Android Studio` and it's working fine like you mentioned.

> Current `ConstraintLayout` dependency : 
>   `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3`

[image: Example]

Comment: Try with this `ConstraintLayout` dependency (Not recommended): `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4`

Comment: Works now! So weird. I even changed it back to 1.1.3 (just in case) and still doesn't work. I'll keep an eye out for the stable release. Thank you!

Comment: Broken again in beta6

Answer (score 0):

Despite all these answers I doubt it is possible to achieve what you want with standard means, however some approximation can be done like this:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="#ff0000"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/artist_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="#00ff00"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/header_image"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/header_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guide"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.32" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

An update: in theory (was not testing) you should be able to do something like this actually. Ti should give pixel perfect layout without relying on any absolute values btw:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="#ff0000"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/stub"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/artist_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="#00ff00"
            app:layout_constraintCircle="@+id/stub"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/header_image"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/header_image"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header_image"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.32" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah notice they use some absolute heights, and you're using percentages, one depending on height and the other on width of your screen. That's different.